# How to use the Kubernetes HorizontalPodAutoscaler with the memory metric?

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I'm trying to understand how the Kubernetes **HorizontalPodAutoscaler** works.
Until now, I have used the following configuration:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-deployment
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

This uses the `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage` parameter but I would like to use a metric for the memory percentage used, but I was not able to find any example.
Any hint?

I found also that there is this type of configuration to support multiple metrics, but the **apiVersion** is `autoscaling/v2alpha1`. Can this be used in a production environment?

```
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2alpha1
metadata:
  name: WebFrontend
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: ReplicationController
    name: WebFrontend
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      targetAverageUtilization: 80
  - type: Object
    object:
      target:
        kind: Service
        name: Frontend
      metricName: hits-per-second
      targetValue: 1k
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a manifest example for what you need, that includes **Memory Metrics**:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: web-servers
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: web-servers
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 20
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 30Mi
```

An important thing to notice is that, as you can see, it uses the **autoscaling/v2beta2 API version**, so you need to follow all the previous instructions listed [here](https://loft.sh/blog/kubernetes-horizontal-pod-autoscaling/).

Regarding the possibility to use the **autoscaling/v2alpha1**, yes, you can use it, as it includes support for scaling on memory and custom metrics as this [URL](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) specifies, but keep in mind that alpha versions are released for testing, as they are not final versions.

For more **autoscaling/v2beta2 YAML’s** examples and a deeper look into memory metrics, you can take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69184304/how-memory-metric-is-evaluated-by-kubernetes-hpa).